# "no parameterless constructor defined for this object" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, constructor, ninject, moq

I am getting an error. I am using Moq and Ninject. Here are the detailed error message:

> [MissingMethodException: no parameterless constructor defined for this
>   object]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type,
>   Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +232    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +66    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +55
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a
>   controller of type 'EF.Controllers.ProductController'. Make sure that
>   the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +179
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) +74
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   +193    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +301    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Here is my Controller :

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository repository;

    public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        this.repository = productRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult List()
    {
        return View(repository.Products);
    }

}
```

*RouteConfig* points out the *List* ActionMethod. Here is the content of the *IProductRepository*:

> ```
> public interface IProductRepository
> {
>     IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
> }
> ```

Here is the definition of the Product:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the *NinjectControllerFactory* class:

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{

    private IKernel ninjectKernel;

    public NinjectControllerFactory()
    {
        ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
        AddBindings();
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return controllerType == null
        ? null
        : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// An binding has been implemented there. I am creating a Mock object, and I embedded it.
    /// </summary>
    private void AddBindings()
    {
        Mock<IProductRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();

        mock.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(new List<Product> {
        new Product { Name = "Football", Price = 25 },
        new Product { Name = "Surf board", Price = 179 },
        new Product { Name = "Running shoes", Price = 95 }
        }.AsQueryable());

        ninjectKernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().ToConstant(mock.Object);
    }
}
```

What I am missing? Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you register your `NinjectControllerFactory` in MVC? It seems from the stack trace that your custom controller factory isn't used at all.

Comment: @Steven is right. You probably didn't set correctly your factory: `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof (NinjectControllerFactory )`. [Understanding and Extending Controller Factory in MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/732449/Understanding-and-Extending-Controller-Factory-i)

Comment: Steven, The Old Fox.
You were right. In the Application_Start() I shall add the code : ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new
NinjectControllerFactory()); 
After I wrote it, problem is solved. Your point is right. I can not accept your answers due to the web site.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of Moq is incorrect.  You don't use Moq for dependency injection, you use it for mocking an interface (ideally) when unit testing another class that has a dependency on that interface.  You shouldn't even be using Moq in the NinjectControllerFactory.

Your `AddBindings()` method should simply be:

```
ninjectKernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<ProductRepository>();
```

Also, usually DI containers have a convention by default approach, which should allow you to not even need to use the `Bind<>().To<>()` statement there. I'm not as familiar with Ninject, but I will try to find a sample for you.

Comment: I got the code from the book "Pro Asp.Net MVC 4, fourth Edition", by Adam Freeman, I suppose he is right.